# Removing the "chapter" title for one chapter only

Tags: chapters

How can I remove the "chapter" title for one chapter only?

E.g. if I want to remove the "chapter" title for chapter 2 only, using

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}
\chapter{World}
\chapter{!}

\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

I would like to obtain instead:

[image]

Comment: Use `\chapter*{World}` to not have the title, and `\stepcounter{chapter}` to keep the chapter numbering consistent.

Comment: @ChrisS - One should probably use `\refstepcounter` rather than `\stepcounter`, as all kinds of cross-referencing mechanisms rely on counters being stepped via `\refstepcounter`.

Comment: @Mico `\refstepcounter` would be necessary only if one wants to set a label for the (inexistent) number. Otherwise `\stepcounter` is as good. On the other hand it' difficult to understand why chapter two shouldn't receive its number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The chapter head is set in [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) by the macro `\@makechapterhead`:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

We can create a "duplicate" of it, only with the creation of `Chapter X` removed. Let's call this duplicate `\fake@makechapterhead`:

```
\def\fake@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \strut%\@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

The commented part has been replaced by `\strut` (in order to have an appropriate baseline correctly set.

Now we add some house-keeping and user-interface macros and you can use `\newchapterhead` to create the "fake" chapter head, and `\restorechapterhead` to restore the original setting:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\let\old@makechapterhead\@makechapterhead
% Taken from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls
\def\fake@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \strut%\@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\newcommand{\newchapterhead}{\let\@makechapterhead\fake@makechapterhead}
\newcommand{\restorechapterhead}{\let\@makechapterhead\old@makechapterhead}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}

\newchapterhead
\chapter{World}

\restorechapterhead
\chapter{!}

\end{document}
```

The above procedure keeps the same vertical location for the chapter title by merely removing the phrase `Chapter X` from being printed.

---

An alternative approach might be to use the `\chapter*` setting of a chapter. This doesn't provide the same vertical position on the chapter-page for the title, but may also be what you're after:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}

\clearpage\refstepcounter{chapter}%
\chapter*{World}

\chapter{!}

\end{document}
```

The issuing of a `\clearpage\refstepcounter{chapter}` allows for two things:

1. Steps the `chapter` counter to have a correct reference for sub-content in chapter `World`;
2. Correct mark in the document if you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) for placing a internal document hyperlink.